# Transfering large amount of data across multiple sites

Tags: php, json, oop

Recently I ran into a problem - my current method of transferring language strings across multiple sites used up too much memory. Basically I simply created an array of data on one server and echoed it out with json.

E.g. -

```
$data = array(1, 2, 3);
echo json_encode($data);
```

> PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2302769209 bytes) in [..]

The main idea is **to transfer language strings from a language editor to my site as soon as my client clicks `update`**.

The thing is, this x-fer is going on quite frequently (as soon as my client clicks the `update` button on the site) and it'd be hard to do always do it by hand.

So my question is:
**How do you transfer such a large array of data across multiple sites?**

Obviously, my solution wasn't good enough.

Comment: How often do you need to send data? Does it change often? Perhaps you could consider cashing it

Comment: Break it up into pieces. Many ways to do that. Best way depends on circumstances.

Comment: @Darvex Perhaps once, maybe twice a week. It changes on a daily basis.

Comment: @joshp And what then? Should I break it up in, lets say, 10 pieces and make a new request for each piece? And now theoretically speaking - what if just 10 users press the `update` button in the same moment? 100 requests?

Comment: @Bag: Really depends on your circumstances, which I don't know. But yes, I would look at either writing it to a file system, to a big db, or streaming it to the other servers. If you don't use some sort of streaming or chunking mechanism with this size of data the 10 users hitting update will really eat your RAM. Would be happy to discuss.

Comment: @Bag, do all users get same updated data? That is, the data changes once and all users who press update get the same information?

Comment: @Darvex No, each one of the users has it's own unique information (translation strings that need to be synced with the site).

Comment: @joshp, The idea behind this is quite simple: I have to create a way how my clients can sync the language strings from the panel to the main site. The panel is a separate web-app that's on a different server. Sometimes they need to sync like 2k language strings and that's when my system fails. It simply runs out of memory and I don't think that increasing my cap on memory would solve anything. It'd just kill my servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some experience with such questions. Simple way to fix your problem is to split that array for some requests.